# How disable jquery mobile's style in the entire contents of a div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I work on a jQuery Mobile's project.

In a page, I want use `mobilescroll` for an select (http://demo.mobiscroll.com/select#language=fr&display=inline)

I try `data-role="none"`, but it doesn't work on the children
and `mobilescroll` create their own tags.

How disable jQuery Mobile's style in the entire contents of a `div` ?

Thanks

Comment: You can't disable the styles like that. The best you could do is create a new page without the jQuery Mobile styles, and then insert that into your first page with an iFrame.

Comment: there is a css file you can download it from jquerymobile.com that without default theme ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to prevent jQuery Mobile from enhancing elements. however, following this solution will make your application slower than usual.

> **[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/kGYtM/)**

First, you need to globally set *ignoreContentEnabled* to *true*.

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>          
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
      $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
    });
  </script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And then, add `data-enhance="false"` attribute to elements which you don't want JQM to enhance. This is the reason why app becomes slow, because JQM checks for this attribute in all elements.